# Могу ли я средствами jpegoptim и optipng сжать изображения на сервере CentOS только в рамках одного сайта?

Tags: linux, centos, png, jpeg

> Конфигурация:
>
> - WEB-Сервер: Apache
> - ОС: CentOS 7.x
> - Виртуальная машина: BitrixVM
> - Версия PHP: 7.1.23

На сервер есть несколько сайтов.

Нужно сжать изображения только на одном сайте.

Могу ли я средствами jpegoptim и optipng сжать изображения на сервере CentOS только в рамках одного сайта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Да, т.к. это стандартный процесс сжатия.

---

### Стандартный процесс сжатия

Установка:

```
sudo apt-get install jpegoptim optipng -y
```

Сжатие графические изображения средствами `jpegoptim`:

```
find /home/bitrix/ext_www/example.com/upload/resize_cache/ -type f -regex ".*\(jpg\|jpeg\|JPG\|JPEG\)" -exec jpegoptim --preserve --preserve-perms --max=85 {} \;  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Сжатие графические изображения средствами `optipng`:

```
find /home/bitrix/ext_www/example.com/upload/resize_cache/ -type f -regex ".*\(png\|PNG\)" -print -exec optipng -o5 -quiet -keep -preserve {} \;
```

---

### Решение вопроса

Для решения вопроса, необходимо в скрипте сжатия изменить  путь к директории.

Например директорию:

```
/home/bitrix/ext_www/example.com/upload/resize_cache/
```

Меняем на:

```
/home/bitrix/ext_www/example.com/upload/upload/iblock/
```